# Why does my Autohotkey script add empty lines, when I copy the clipboard and paste it?

Tags: autohotkey

My script is:

```
oCB := ClipboardAll ; old Clipboard
clipboard = ; Emptying clipboard to prepare for ClipWait
Sendinput, ^c
ClipWait
selected_text = %clipboard%
Send, %selected_text%
ClipBoard := oCB ; restore ClipBoard

return
```

Presently it adds empty lines. If I use it on

```
Alice
Bob
Carol
```

I get

```
Alice

Bob

Carol
```

What is happening here? How do I keep the text constant, so I can manipulate it to my choosing without having side-effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason `Send` or the program that receives the text, interprets `r`n as two newlines, so the simplest solution is to remove `r from the string.

Add this line before sending the text:

```
StringReplace, selected_text , selected_text , `r , , All
```